# Big O Notation and with Functions as Exponents

Tags: discrete-mathematics

It is right to assume that if $f$ and $g$ are $O(h)$ then $f^g$ is $O(h^h)$? The base ($f$) and the exponent ($g$) are both less than $h$ for some $c$.

Comment: See what happens if $f(x)=2x$, $g(x)=3x$, $h(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not right: you have to assume further conditions on $f$ and $g$.  As counterexamples you have the one pointed out by @GerryMyerson in the comments to the question or the following one, where $f$ and $g$ are controlled by $h$ with the same bounding constant $c=1$.
$$
\begin{split}
f(x)&=\frac{\sin(x)}{|x|+1}\\
g(x)&=\frac{\cos(x)}{|x|+1}
\end{split}
\quad h(x)=\frac{1}{|x|+1}\;\Longrightarrow\;
\begin{split}
f&=O(h)\\
g&=O(h)
\end{split}
$$
However, 
$$
f^g\neq O(h^h)
$$
since $h^h$ is bounded on the whole $\mathbb{R}$ while $f^g\to\infty$ if $x\to (2n+1)\pi$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.